# Make WP media not to accept .html file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Right now Wp Media Uploader acepting .html file due to which there is change of uploading misleading and virus html file so we want to make not to accept html file,can anyone eplains us how to do that in WP

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of upload_mimes hook of wordpress to unset the any file extensions. The code goes to functions.php.

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', function(array $mimes){ 
    unset($mimes['html']);
    return $mimes;
});
```

Comment: but by this media uploader has giving access to upload .html file

Comment: Here it is using the unset() method to remove the .html from the mimes.

Comment: You can check this example from the wordpress docs.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_mimes/

Comment: Yes but when i put that code and tried to upload .html file then it's been uploading so how  it's works?